# Regularity of a measure $n(E) = \int_{E} f(x) dx$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> I would like to show that the (positive) measure $n$ on $\Bbb R \setminus \{0\}$ defined by $n(E) = \displaystyle \int_E \frac{dx}{|x|}$
>   is outer regular ($dx$ being the usual Lebesgue measure).

— In particular, I have to show that for any fixed Borel set $E$, I have
$$\forall \epsilon>0 \quad \exists O \supset E \text{ open,} \quad 0 ≤ n(O)-n(E)<\epsilon$$

If $n(E)=\infty$, then this is trivial. If $n(E)<\infty$, then $f(x) = 1/x$ is $L^1(E,m)$ and by regularity of the Lebesgue measure $m$, we have :
$$\exists O \supset E \text{ open,} \quad m(O)-m(E)<\epsilon/ \|f\|_{L^1(E,m)}$$

— But I don't know how to conclude. The minus sign in $-n(E)$ bothers me, and even if I had a function $f$ in $L^1(\Bbb R \setminus \{0\})$ (with $f \geq 0$), I wouldn't know how to do it.

Could I say $$n(O)-n(E) = n(O \setminus E) = \int_{O \setminus E} \frac{dx}{|x|} \leq m(O \setminus E) \|f\|_{L^1(O,m)} < \epsilon$$ if I suppose that $f \in  L^1(O,m)$ and I take $m(O)-m(E)<\epsilon/ \|f\|_{L^1(O,m)}$ ?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: You should be clear about what sort of measure you are talking about, because most measures can't be negative, but $n(E)$ can be.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews : oops! I wanted to write $dx/|x|$… Is it clearer now?

Comment: By the regularity of the Lebesgue measure, every Lebesgue-measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is the union of an $F_{\sigma}$ and a null set, and it is also a $G_{\delta}$ minus a null set.